# Exception in a CRM LINQ query with joins. Attribute in second table doesn't exist

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

First of all I'm sorry because this is the second time that I write this question but before was bad explained and now is close.

I'm doing a linq query for a search page for a CRM data base, and wrtiting a normal query like below is not working, I'm getting the exception:

```
 [System.ServiceModel.FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>] = {"'Contact' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'title'."}
```

For a join query, that in the clause Where was something like r.Name == "Me" && j.LastName == "He" I had to did the query with two Where clauses, because I was getting the same exception as above, saying that table 'r' doesn't have 'LastName' attributte.

```
var cms = from i in aux_pr
       join cal in Contact on i.aux_CallerRequestorID.Id equals cal.ContactId.Value
       join sub in Subject on i.aux_ClassificationID.Id equals sub.SubjectId
       where cal.FullName.Contains(searchTerm) ||
       sub.Title.Contains(searchTerm)
```

In this case, how can I do this query. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can edit first question, expect of creating new one

Comment: The message indicates that your client thinks there is a title attribute and dynamics thinks there isn't. Resolve the config issue. I know nothing about dynamics, btw. Just reading the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to comment what have I learned and the solution that I have found to my problem hoping could help some one. There are some limitations in CRM LINQ, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422514/linq-to-crm-or-in-where-clause)

The first that I found, having an entity reference like this:

```
CrmEntityReference Caller
{
   Guid ID;
   string name;    
}
```

I can select Caller.name but I CAN'T have Caller.name in the where clause. Solution for this -> Join the table

The second limitation, is when we have joins in the query, we can have different tables in the where if they are an AND predicate, we have to write two clauses where like this:

```
   where cal.FullName.Contains(searchTerm)
   where sub.Title.Contains(searchTerm)
```

But the problem comes when instead of an AND we need use an OR predicate, the only solution we have is do two queries and after do an Union of these queries.

I have four queries for a call that could be done just with one, now in developing stage performance is good due to the amount of records, but we'll see in testing stage how this work.

Comment: I would like to emphasize "But the problem comes when instead of an AND we need use an OR predicate, the only solution we have is do two queries and after do an Union of these queries." — this is exactly when this problem comes up.

Answer (score 0):

try to create two different filters..

```
   var cms = from i in aux_pr
   join cal in Contact on i.aux_CallerRequestorID.Id equals cal.ContactId.Value
   join sub in Subject on i.aux_ClassificationID.Id equals sub.SubjectId
   where cal.FullName.Contains(searchTerm) ||
   where sub.Title.Contains(searchTerm)
```

Comment: Hi! I tried already this, but I was getting 'Invalid expression term where'

Comment: just make it AND logic and try to see if the error is syntax related...remove || (OR) and just try to execute for sake of testing the  AND logic        where cal.FullName.Contains(searchTerm) 
   where sub.Title.Contains(searchTerm)

Comment: no, there aren't syntax errors, I have wrote like:                 where    cont.FullName.Contains(searchTerm)                                     where    sub.Title.Contains(searchTerm)                              And is working, doesn't get any result , neither any exception.

Comment: ok so that means the two filter thing works its just the || (OR) LOGIC that you will have to figure out ...

Comment: Yes that's it. Reading about I have seen that this seems a know problem with CRM LINQ: each "where" clause can operate only on one Entity type. I have not found any solution yet, but if I do I'll share with all of you and if someone could help me would be great!

Comment: where (cal.FullName.Contains(searchTerm)) || (where (sub.Title.Contains(searchTerm))).....try this.. if not then  maybe play around with the brackets.

Comment: yes I was doing stuff like that and doesn't work, if I write two Where with the OR, always says: invalid term 'where' .But thanks for the attempts.

Comment: sorry wasn't able to help you out much...anyways update the answer if you find ...