# Combining LINQ queries in LINQ to CRM causes problems?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-4

Something weird is going on.

If I do this:

```
        var allAccountsQuery = from acc in baseQ
                               where
                                   //high potential check - 1, 2, 3
                               (acc.mcpl_potencjal_klienta == 1 || acc.mcpl_potencjal_klienta == 2 || acc.mcpl_potencjal_klienta == 3) &&
                                   //directors block check
                               ((acc.mcpl_blokada_dyrektorska == true && acc.mcpl_blokada_do <= date) || acc.mcpl_blokada_dyrektorska == false || acc.mcpl_blokada_dyrektorska == null) &&
                                   //sack assign date check
                               (acc.mcpl_dataprzypisaniazworka == null || acc.mcpl_dataprzypisaniazworka < date) &&
                                   //owner change check
                               (acc.mcpl_datazmianywasciciela == null || acc.mcpl_datazmianywasciciela < date) &&
                                   //creation date check
                                   //TODO:For testing!
                                   //(acc.mcpl_data_utworzenia_test < date)
                               (acc.createdon < date)
                               select acc;

        var joinQuery = from acc in allAccountsQuery
                        join opp in ctx.opportunityopportunities on acc.accountid equals opp.customerid.Value
                        select new
                        {
                            Account = acc,
                            Opportunity = opp
                        };

        Plugins.Common.XrmHelper.ClearCache("account");
        var joinResult = joinQuery.ToList();
```

Then I'll get an unknown platform error when executing this query. I need to copy-paste the WHOLE `where` clause from `allAccountsQuery` to the `joinQuery` and use `baseQ` again, and then it works.

What's going on here? I thought you can safely join LINQ queries as long as you're not doing any unsupported operations.

PS. The STRANGEST part is that the pasted code WILL work with slightly different `where` conditions.

PPS. `baseQ` is just an even simpler `where` query, much like the `allAccountsQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the answer but as I can't leave a comment and no one has answer I think this could help.
Why you don't do the join in the first query? As from I know the LINQ CRM queries have problems joining tables when in the clause WHERE we have the OR Predicate, and not when we try to select from different tables, I think for you query should work. I have one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13644870/1528483.) explaining what I learned.

Comment: I can't join first because LINQ to CRM (4.0) join is an inner join. Attempting to do a left join ended with the CRM throwing an exception in my face.

Answer (score 0):

Linq-to-CRM has a limited set of supported operations compared to other providers life EF or Linq-to-SQL.

You may have better success hydrating one or both of the two queries.  Since your `account` query has a where clause try hydrating it:

```
var joinQuery = from acc in allAccountsQuery.ToList()   // call ToList() to hydrate the query
                join opp in ctx.opportunityopportunities
                   on acc.accountid equals opp.customerid.Value
                select new
                {
                    Account = acc,
                    Opportunity = opp
                };
```

If you have a LARGE number of `Opportunities` you may want to try and filter that query based on the accounts returned from the first query before doing the `Join`.

Comment: The weirdness of the query I posted was that, even disregarding joins, it would sometimes stop working all of a sudden (when I tried `.ToList()` on `allAccountsQuery`... Like I wrote, weird. o_O